# Azure AD B2C authenticate with existing on-perm service

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have authentication service as REST api on premise. 
There are existing users and service could authenticate them by passing the username and password.
Can I configure the Azure B2C to call this existing authentication REST api to authenticate? Is there any [Azure samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples) similar to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can integrate an Azure AD B2C custom policy with a REST service as described by [the **Integrate REST API claims exchanges in your Azure AD B2C user journey as validation of user input** article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-validation) in the Azure AD B2C documentation.

An example of validating a user credential using a REST API can be found in [the Wingtip sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c).

In this Wingtip sample, [a technical profile](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_base.xml#L2300) is declared, which represents the REST API:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="ClassicAccount-CheckPassword">
  <DisplayName>Classic Account Check Password</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://wingtipidentityb2c.azurewebsites.net/api/account/checkpassword</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
    <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Form</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_WingTipClassicAccountClientId" />
    <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_WingTipClassicAccountClientSecret" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="userName" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" />
  </InputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SSOSession-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

This technical profile is [invoked](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com_B2C_1A_base.xml#L2490) during the sign-in flow:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccount-Login">
  <DisplayName>WingTip Account</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccount.login</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
    <Item Key="SignUpTarget">LocalAccountRegistrationExchange</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ClassicAccount-CheckPassword" />
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="LocalAccount-OpenIdConnect" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SSOSession-AzureActiveDirectory" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

[The API implementation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/54a6ac7bc65ce0ae4c6b5eb3f0621f5da5310dfc/wingtipgamesb2c/src/WingTipIdentityWebApplication/Api/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L90) validates the user credential and then migrates the user account from a SQL Server database to the Azure AD B2C directory.

(The user migration is optional.)

Comment: Thanks Chris. I tried with custom policies, calling the rest service.

Comment: The rest service returned the auth-token, when called from B2c. From Azure B2c, a new token is generated and sending its own token to the reply url, how to avoid this new token and use the auth token from rest service instead to reply url?

Comment: I believe the article referenced should be this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-validation

Comment: Thanks @yunspace that has been fixed.